# Bootstrap - styling the toggle button on nav for mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried googling this but am struggling to find the correct selector/class and I'm still quite new to bootstrap.

I'm trying to style my navigation menu on mobile. Here's an image, for reference; I'd like to change the glyphicon here (I believe it's a hamburger at the minute), and its colour.

[image: The area I want to modify]

I'd also like to increase the distance between the nav bar and the cascading bottom menu here:

[image: Right now it looks like a 1px line]

At the minute it looks like a 1px line.

I've tried modifying quite a few selectors in css but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assuming Bootstrap 3

To change the icon find:

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

and replace with:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

And to change the color of the new glyphicon add to your CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle span {
    color: RED;
}
```

### Line below toggle

```
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top-width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question - when I add a border in .navbar-collapse, there's a 1px outer border outside the whole thing. Is that from the parent .navbar selector? I'm looking for a way to create a gap, i.e. having them both totally separate.

Comment: You can check what attributes are coming from where in developer console. In Google Chrome it's F12.